# DatabaseObjectNotClosedException in console

Tags: android, exception, cursor

So I am just finalizing everything on an app I have been working on for a while. The only error I am getting in the console is a DatabaseObjectNotClosedException. It does not cause the app to close or crash or anything, but I am concerned about this as I have read that an unclosed cursor could be a big problem.

So here is the error message:

05-28 20:40:01.598: E/Database(655): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Here is the code it is referring to:

```
    datasource = new ProgressDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();
```

Here is the code for the ProgressDataSource:

```
package com.gauv.myapp;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;

public class ProgressDataSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public ProgressDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public GraphViewData[] fetchProgress(long dayExerciseDataID) {      
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_1RM + " " +
                "from " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOGS + " " +
                "where " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_DAY_EXERCISE + "='" + dayExerciseDataID + "' " +
                "order by " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + " desc limit 30", null);

        GraphViewData[] data = new GraphViewData[cursor.getCount()];
        Long[] onerms = new Long[cursor.getCount()];

        int i = 0;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) 
        {
            onerms[i] = cursor.getLong(0);
            i++;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(onerms));

        int y = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < onerms.length; x++) {
            data[x] = new GraphViewData(y, onerms[x]);
            y++;
        }

        return data;
    }

    public String fetchProgressCount(long dayExerciseDataID) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_1RM + " " +
                "from " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOGS + " " +
                "where " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_DAY_EXERCISE + "='" + dayExerciseDataID + "' " +
                "order by " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + " desc limit 12", null);

        return String.valueOf(cursor.getCount());
    }
}
```

Do I simply need to add `cursor.close()` to the fetchProgress function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your database after you are done with it so all you need to do is call `datasource.close()` and yes you should also close any cursors that you are not using anymore to release it from memory

Comment: I just had to add that to the onPause function in my activity and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates you left a database connection open. Your code snippet confirms this. A good practice is to get the information from your cursor into some domain object and then clean up both the cursor and connection.

Code example:

```
// open db connection
DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
db.open();

// retrieve your items using a cursor object
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SOME_DB", null); 

// iterate all your items here and move to some collection or domain model 
// ...

// and clean up your mess
cursor.close();
db.close();
```